# O site mudou de estilo visual?

Tags: support

Acho que o pt.se acabou de mudar de cores azuis para laranjas. É só impressão minha ou há alguma razão para esta mudança?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Foi uma mudança temporária acidental que afetou toda a [rede](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367641/why-did-all-sites-turn-orange/367643#367643):

> We just pushed a build [Taryn ♦]
>
> Fixed!
> We’ve got a new theming API in Stacks that was leaking a bit. Funnily enough, all the themes we happened to test via smoke tests already had orange buttons so we didn't catch it. [Aaron Shekey ♦]